# NullPointerException while making an asmx web service call for JSON data object from Android App using Volley in Android Studio

Tags: rest, nullpointerexception, android-volley, asmx

I am working on [Arnab's tutorial on Volley from this site](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/). I am getting a NullPointerException while making an asmx web service call for JSON data object from Android App using Volley in Android Studio. The "req" variable is causing the error in line 84 but I clearly declare it before the offending line of code is run. Here is the error from the monitor:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.caduceususa.app.myApp, PID: 14603
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.caduceususa.app.myApp.ApplicationController.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
at com.caduceususa.app.myApp.ConsumeWS$1.onClick(ConsumeWS.java:84)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have three JAVA files in this project. The first contains onCreate here:

```
package com.caduceususa.app.myApp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;


public class ConsumeWS extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_consume_ws);

        final Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        final TextView status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.connStatus);
        final TextView response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.serverResp);


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                status.setText("Connection Requested...");
                response.setText("waiting...");
                JSONObject oCreds = new JSONObject();

                final String URL = "https://myApp.caduceususa.com/ws/myApp.asmx/myAppLogin";

                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("sName", "email@email.com");
                params.put("sPass", "password");

                JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
                ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

            }
        });
    }



    public class JsonObjectRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONObject> {
        /**
         * Creates a new request.
         * @param method the HTTP method to use
         * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
         * @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONObject} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
         *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
         * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
         * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
         */
        public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                                 Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                    errorListener);
        }
        /**
         * Constructor which defaults to <code>GET</code> if <code>jsonRequest</code> is
         * <code>null</code>, <code>POST</code> otherwise.
         *
         * @see #JsonObjectRequest(int, String, JSONObject, Listener, ErrorListener)
         */
        public JsonObjectRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                                 ErrorListener errorListener) {
            this(jsonRequest == null ? Method.GET : Method.POST, url, jsonRequest,
                    listener, errorListener);
        }
        @Override
        protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                String jsonString =
                        new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My ApplicationController JAVA file is as follows:

```
package com.caduceususa.app.myApp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class ApplicationController extends Application {

    /**
     * Log or request TAG
     */
    public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";

    /**
     * Global request queue for Volley
     */
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    /**
     * A singleton instance of the application class for easy access in other places
     */
    private static ApplicationController sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // initialize the singleton
        sInstance = this;
    }

    /**
     * @return ApplicationController singleton instance
     */
    public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * @return The Volley Request queue, the queue will be created if it is null
     */
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
        // created when it is accessed for the first time
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue, if tag is specified
     * then it is used else Default TAG is used.
     *
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

        VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue using the Default TAG.
     *
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TAG);

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Cancels all pending requests by the specified TAG, it is important
     * to specify a TAG so that the pending/ongoing requests can be cancelled.
     *
     * @param tag
     */
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an error helper:

```
package com.caduceususa.app.myApp;

import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class VolleyErrorHelper {
    /**
     * Returns appropriate message which is to be displayed to the user
     * against the specified error object.
     *
     * @param error
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static String getMessage(Object error, Context context) {
        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
            return context.getResources().getString(R.string.generic_server_down);
        }
        else if (isServerProblem(error)) {
            return handleServerError(error, context);
        }
        else if (isNetworkProblem(error)) {
            return context.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet);
        }
        return context.getResources().getString(R.string.generic_error);
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether the error is related to network
     * @param error
     * @return
     */
    private static boolean isNetworkProblem(Object error) {
        return (error instanceof NetworkError) || (error instanceof NoConnectionError);
    }
    /**
     * Determines whether the error is related to server
     * @param error
     * @return
     */
    private static boolean isServerProblem(Object error) {
        return (error instanceof ServerError) || (error instanceof AuthFailureError);
    }
    /**
     * Handles the server error, tries to determine whether to show a stock message or to
     * show a message retrieved from the server.
     *
     * @param err
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    private static String handleServerError(Object err, Context context) {
        VolleyError error = (VolleyError) err;

        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;

        if (response != null) {
            switch (response.statusCode) {
                case 404:
                case 422:
                case 401:
                    try {
                        // server might return error like this { "error": "Some error occured" }
                        // Use "Gson" to parse the result
                        HashMap<String, String> result = new Gson().fromJson(new String(response.data),
                                new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
                                }.getType());

                        if (result != null && result.containsKey("error")) {
                            return result.get("error");
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // invalid request
                    return error.getMessage();

                default:
                    return context.getResources().getString(R.string.generic_server_down);
            }
        }
        return context.getResources().getString(R.string.generic_error);
    }
}
```

Finally here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.caduceususa.app.myApp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ConsumeWS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am really not sure where to start to debug here as I have seen multiple suggested solutions that which I have tried and I figure let me just put the code out there and maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Marcin, I declare it here: JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params)

Comment: what precisely code is in ConsumeWS.java line 84?

Comment: ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

Comment: Its directly below: JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params)

Comment: Crickets... Why delegitimize my question and then not even try to answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ApplicationController class in  manifest tag, because it is missing that android:name attribute. As it is not referenced there that is why you are getting NPE.

Disclaimer: I am the author of that blog post from where this piece of code is referenced (volley usage part)

Comment: Thanks Arnab, adding a link to your blog to OG Post

Comment: Maybe adding a little clarification on that in that post may help others in the future, just a thought and thank you

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth sure, will do